# RegEx match string if contains specific word

Tags: html, regex, optimization

here is an example text:

> **[ame=\"watch?v=12345\"]YouTube - blah lorem blah blah [/ame]** Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
>   Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
>   1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it
>   to make a type specimen book. **[ame=\"watch?v=123456\"]YouTube - blah
>   blah blah [/ame]** It has survived not only five centuries, but also
>   the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
>   It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
>   containing **[ame=\"watch?v=1234\"]YouTube - blah Ω blah lorem
>   [/ame]** Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
>   publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
>   Ipsum.

I need a regex that match only the [ame][/ame] with word **lorem** inside. Also, in last [ame] instance there is a special character (letter Omega in Greek) **Ω**. I need a regex to match [ame] with omega(Ω) inside, too.

I tried `(\[ame=[^\]]*\])([lorem])(\[\/ame\])` but nothing happens. Please check it [here](http://regexr.com/3badt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't mention anything about group captures the first solution does not use them:

```
/\[ame[^\[]+lorem[^\[]*\[\/ame\]/g
```

Breaking this down:

- `\[ame`: start match with "ame" opening tag
- `[^\[]+`: continue match until first "["
- `lorem`: match "lorem"
- `[^\[]*`: continue match until first "["
- `\[\/ame\]`: end match with "ame" closing tag

The special sauce are the two greedy matches that combined with the match for "lorem" will only match an "ame" tag containing "lorem". This approach doesn't care where "lorem" occurs within the tag (it could be in the link rather than the text).

The second solution is if you do care about capture groups (say for the link and text values) and that "lorem" only occur in the text value. Building on the same concepts for the first solution but adding in the group captures gives:

```
/\[ame=\\"([^"]+)\\"\]([^\[]*lorem[^\[]*)\[\/ame\]/g
```

Breaking this one down:

- `\[ame=\\"([^"]+)\\"\]`: start match with "ame" opening tag using a group capture for the link value
- `([^\[]*lorem[^\[]*)`: match text value containing "lorem" with a second group capture
- `\[\/ame\]`: end match with "ame" closing tag

The text value match is similar to the previous solution's match but now accounts that the text value might only be "lorem" (since the previous solution just matched the entire tag).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, your way seems to work. I have to tried to my original text and tell you the results. I appreciate your long and detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution:

```
(\[ame=[^\]]*\])[^[]*?lorem[^[]*?(\[\/ame\])
```

I did not optimize it in any way.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern in the middle (`lorem`) must not be enclosed in `[]`:

```
/(\[ame=[^\]]*\]).*(lorem).*(\[\/ame\])/
```

see here: https://regex101.com/r/eC9sS5/1

http://regexr.com/3bae0

Comment: This matches any `[ame]` with the last possible `[/ame]`, including a lot of unneeded information inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

So other answers still have considerable flaws (that of not being able to have symbol `[` between `ame` tags and the omega part is also ignored, though easy to do).

The issue is similar to that of regex HTML parsing. If you want to have info between `[ame]` and `[/ame]` the tags can repeat during the course of the document. The issue is showcased here: https://regex101.com/r/rC3eK4/1 , where the tag will "jump" to the next one to have the set requirements . To avoid this, other answers have pointed out that they just wont allow `[` in the character list. However, who's to say that you can't have a different tag within? `[ame] this is [b]bolded[/b][/ame]`.

I would suggest a two-step solution. First extract the contents of all `[ame]` tags with `\[ame.*?\].*?\[\/ame\]`. https://regex101.com/r/rC3eK4/2 . This will extract the `ame` tags even with adition tags inside. 
Then see if you can match the contents with what you were asking with `\[ame.*?\](?:(.*?lorem.*?)|(.*?Ω.*?))\[\/ame\]`, as seen https://regex101.com/r/rC3eK4/3 . It will also capture the contents you want in the `$1` capture group.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I see your point here with the possibility of extra brackets inside the text. But something weird happens. I took your last example and added some text between the [ame][/ame] and it cannot parse it correct. Please check here [link](https://regex101.com/r/rC3eK4/7)